# Macro VBA formatting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hello I have the following MACRO...

```
Sub RunThis()
With Application
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     .ScreenUpdating = False

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conditions").Range("A27:H54").Copy

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project")
      .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
 End With

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conditions").Range("A56:H88").Copy

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project")
      .Range("A29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .Range("A29").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
 End With
 Call DeleteCellsWithNo
 End With
**With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project")
    .Cells("A, 1").Select
End With**
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is Make is select the Cell A1 - also, I'm trying to format the width of cell A1 to autowidth....Any idea?

EDIT: the two stars next to WITH is what i'm trying to do but it gives me an error

EDIT2:

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project")
        .Cells(1, "A").Select
        .Cells(1, "A").Width = 50
    End With
```

I have this but gives me errors on the WIDTH part. I guess I want to set the width because the values are of different length so 50 will work for all

Comment: `.Cells("A, 1").Select` is incorrect.  `Cells()` format is `Cells(Row,Column)` so in your case `.Cells(1,1)` or `.Cells(1,"A")`

Comment: To your Edit2: `.Cells(1, "A").ColumnWidth = 50`  Width is not a function of a range object.

Comment: @ScottCraner post an answer ill accept thanks

Comment: Also for stuff like this, the built macro recorder is often a fast answer.  I have used it many times to create the skeleton of a needed macro.

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand your point, but if you want to autowidth your cell (your column) this works:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project").Columns("A:A").AutoFit
```